# Losing value from the table id in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and I have 2 tables with these columns:

```
table structures__|id|name|nation_id|image|

table nations______|id|nation|
```

"nation_id" column is linked to nations´s table and returns nations´s table "id" column. I want to make a query from structures to get the values from "name" and "image" columns plus get the nation associated with the nation_id.

But in my code the nations's id column ends up becoming the id of the structures´s table. I'm still able to get the correct value from "name" but because I need the original structures "id" to get the correct "image".

This is the code I'm using:

```
$nation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["nation"]);
$nameN = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["nameN"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM structures 
LEFT JOIN nations ON structures.nations_id = nations.id
WHERE nations_id LIKE '$nation' and nations.nation like '$nameN'";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*, n.nation
FROM structures AS s
JOIN nations AS n ON s.nation_id = n.id
WHERE n.id = '$nation'
AND n.nation = '$nameN'
```